# Library to manage an online form and its responses

Tags: library, database, html, python

I need to set up an online questionnaire with multiple questions and choices. This questionnaire needs to auto-update (add more choices) as responses come in. I'm more proficient in Python than in any other languages, so I am wondering if there is a Python library which could help set up this kind of system.

In short, the system should consist of:

1. A simple-looking but multi-question HTML form;
2. A very simple database
3. A script that would update 1. according to 2.

Comment: Flask + Flask-WTForms